# next.js 13.4 > loading skeleton

Tags: web, next.js, frontend

i have a problem with showing loading skeleton, while my categories (fakestore api ) are fetching , could someone provide with the right way how to do it simply ? here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Suspense } from 'react';
import Image from 'next/image';
import Search from '@/components/Search/page';
import heroImage from '/public/images/mainHome.png';
import styles from './home.module.scss';
// import ProductItem from '@/components/productItem.jsx';
import ProductItem from '@/components/ProductItem.jsx';
import Categories from '@/components/Categories';
import RedButton from '@/components/RedButton/page';
import Partners from '@/components/Partners/page';

async function getPopularProducts() {
    const res = await fetch('https://fakestoreapi.com/products?limit=4');
    if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error('Failed to fetch data');
    }
    return res.json();
}

export default async function Home() {
    const data = await getPopularProducts();
    return (
        <div className={styles.container}>
            <Image src={heroImage} alt='Hero image' fill sizes='100vw' style={{ objectFit: 'cover' }} />
            <Search className={styles.search} />
            <h1 className={styles.title}>Популярні товари</h1>
            <section className={styles.products}>
                {data.map(product => (
                    <ProductItem key={product.id} product={product} />
                ))}
            </section>
            <h1 className={`${styles.title} ${styles.categoryTitle}`}>Категорії</h1>
            <section className={styles.sectionCategories}>
                <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
                    <Categories />
                </Suspense>
            </section>
            <div className={styles.allCategory}>
                <RedButton title='Усі категорії' />
            </div>
            <section className={styles.sectionPartners}>
                <Partners />
            </section>
        </div>
    );
}
```

i was trying to create loading.js in the same folder of component but it didn't work , i dont know why